# POST2PDF Converter: issue with aligning content in two column layout

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tcpdf

I am using wordpress POST2PDF Converter plugin. I need to display pdf file in two column layout. I have used table to create a two column layout but there is an issue,

Please see the attached image,

[image]

if the content of the 'abstract' is longer than the first column, it should continue to the second column (and not to the first column of the second page..)

Comment: Refer this http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_020.phps or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563308/tcpdf-multicell-valign-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue. By modifying this http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_010.pdf example I was able to create two column layout. I have removed table structure from the content. Better not to use table for creating column layouts in TCPDF.